# cannot connect to linux tcp socket app from remote host

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, gnu

I wrote an app that uses a TCP socket from the GNU C socket library.  It just basically listens on a socket for incoming requests.  I am able to connect to the socket with telnet on the localhost, but when I try connecting from another machine there is no response.  I'm running Fedora 13 and disabled my firewall, but it still doesn't work.

The socket code is encapsulated in a library that was written by some other organization and is supposed to work already, but here's the meat of it:

```
...
fd_ = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (fd_ < 0)
{
   perror("socket");
   return -1;
}

int val = 1;
int rc = setsockopt(fd_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, sizeof(val));

if (rc < 0)
{
   perror("sesockopt");
   close();
   return -1;
}

rc = setsockopt(fd_, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &val, sizeof(val));

if (rc < 0)
{
   perror("sesockopt");
   close();
   return -1;
}

const int flags = ::fcntl(fd_, F_GETFL, 0);
::fcntl(fd_, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);


rc = ::bind(fd_, addr, addr.size_);

if (rc < 0)
{
   perror("bind");
   close();
   return -1;
}

rc = ::listen(fd_, 10);

if (rc < 0)
{
   perror("bind");
   close();
   return -1;
}

return 0;
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: are you sure you are listening on the correct network address?

Comment: Another classic htons() issue ?

Comment: well i'm using 127.0.0.1 for the ip.  The socket code belongs to a library that was written by another organization a while back, and it is supposed to work.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback device and only acessible from the local host. you could use 0.0.0.0 to listen on all devices or specify the address of the concrete network interface you want to listen on.

Comment: @mata  Thanks, using 0.0.0.0 worked!

Answer (score 1):

In order to accept connections you actually have to call [`accept(2)`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/accept4.2.html) on that TCP socket. As given, the code only prepares the socket for listening on the network.

Also, since you are marking that socket as *non-blocking*, you'd probably want to wrap it in some sort of [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) loop.

Comment: Right, well that does get called in another function.  And I'm able to connect to the socket locally with telnet and transfer data, so the socket code seems to work fine.  I was thinking it's a firewall issue, but after disabling the firewall with system-config-firewall, it still wont work

Comment: You need to give more details then. What address/port you are binding on the server side, how you connect to that from the client?